# How to make purrr code work with spark.lapply?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

How can I make this code work with SparkR's spark.lapply by somehow sending the combination of xs and ys on different nodes to parallelize the calculations? I believe, it should start right between, `tibble(ys, xs)` and `mutate(startformula = paste0(ys, " ~ ", 1)` in the following code, but I don't know how.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

ys <- names(mtcars)

xs <- map(ys, ~setdiff(names(mtcars), .x)) %>% 
  map(~paste0(.x, collapse = "+")) %>%
  unlist()

models <- tibble(ys, xs) %>%
  mutate(startformula = paste0(ys, " ~ ", 1),
         endformula = paste0(ys, " ~ ", xs)) %>% 
  mutate(model = map2(startformula,
                      endformula,
                      ~glm(.x, data=mtcars, family=gaussian, maxit = 100) %>% 
                        step(direction = "forward", scope = .y, trace = FALSE))) %>% 
  mutate(pred = map(model, augment)) %>% 
  mutate(glance = map(model, glance))
```